# What is the proportion of excitatory vs. inhibitory neurons in the feline thalamus?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy

Is there a scientific reference on the numbers (or proportion) of excitatory and inhibitory neurons in the thalamus of the cat?

Comment: have you checked out shepherd's synaptic organization of the brain?

Comment: Oh thanks! I have forgotten the Shepherd's.

Comment: try posting your answer if you find it there

Answer (score 2):

I found two articles:

[Madarasz et.al. (1985)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3940(85)90403-3)
GABA cells

- 27 % LGN
- 33 % Ventrobasal complex
- 25 % Antero-ventral nucleus

[Penny et.al. (1983)](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/3/9/1868.full.pdf)
GAD-immuninoreactive neurons

- 30 % VentroPosterior

<sub>Madarász, M., Somogyi, G., Somogyi, J., & Hamori, J. (1985). [Numerical estimation of γ-aminobutyric acid (GABA)-containing neurons in three thalamic nuclei of the cat: direct GABA immunocytochemistry.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3940(85)90403-3) Neuroscience letters, 61(1), 73-78.

Penny, G. R., Fitzpatrick, D., Schmechel, D. E., & Diamond, I. T. (1983). [Glutamic acid decarboxylase-immunoreactive neurons and horseradish peroxidase-labeled projection neurons in the ventral posterior nucleus of the cat and Galago senegalensis.](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/3/9/1868.full.pdf) The Journal of Neuroscience, 3(9), 1868-1887.</sub>

Comment: i believe, although i am not certain, that there is a difference between the nucleus reuniens and the rest of the nuclei.